# Grant additional permissions inside a facebook app

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I am developing a facebook app, that only exists inside a canvas on facebook. (iframe) After a click on a certain link, I want to display the modal window of facebook that requests the user to add the app and grant it permissions. However, the only thing I can find on this is `FB.login`, that

1. is not capable of showing the popup as a javascript popup/layer
2. tries to log the user in on my app, which I don't want. I want that "add app" dialog with the permission granting.

Is this even possible? The `FB.login()` function only has the options `popup` and `page` (where the first one is real popup and the second one a page *on* facebook).

I am using the JS SDK and OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to get premissions for a page the user has to "log in" to your app.  By logging in they grant your app access to their information within the scope of the requested premissions.

This is a core concept of the OAuth flow.   Your app (client) requests authorization and premission from the authorization server (Facebook login) to access protected resources (Facebook information).

Checkout facebooks sample canvas app that uses the JavaScript SDK:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/

Comment: Thank you. I simply used the login method wrong, since I did not specify a callback function. In the facebook docs there is an example that I copied exactly, but it didn't work. With a callback function given it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following:
    https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?=APPID&next=CANVASS_URL

Remember to replace APPID and CANVASS_URL with your details